# Add Custom Path To include in Google Directions API

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-directory-api

So i've created an app (on iOS) that uses google maps SDK, google places API, google directions api, along with a few other things to run it. I can get directions from current location -> any place and display them. I was wondering if there is any way that I can add custom paths that would be incorporated into google directions api so when I retrieve route directions through google directions API, those paths are included in the route directions. For example, a path that cuts through a park between 1 street in a city and another street in a city. I'm not looking for any code, just a guide or documentation to get started.

Answer (score 0):

> **Using this function you will be get Polyline between tow place.**

```
func getPolylineRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D){

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        let url = URL(string: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&sensor=false&mode=driving")!
        print(url)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                do {
                    if let json : [String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let routes = json["routes"] as? NSArray
                            self.ViewMap.clear()
                            let routeOverviewPolyline:NSDictionary = (routes![0] as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "overview_polyline") as! NSDictionary
                            let points = routeOverviewPolyline.object(forKey: "points")
                            let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points! as! String)
                            let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                            polyline.strokeWidth = 3
                            let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path!)
                            self.ViewMap!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 30.0))
                            polyline.map = self.ViewMap
                        }
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

> **use function like this :-**

```
getPolylineRoute(from: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0350073, 72.5293244), to: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.0497364, 72.5117241))
```

Comment: My problem isn't using directions API. I've already implemented this and been able to get directions from x to y. What I want to do is add (locally to my device or other devices using my code) a way to add a custom route where let's say x to y would normally take 6 minutes going arounda . building, rather it cuts through a park and takes 2 minutes